# How to insert a new record in a table by MAX(ID) + 1 of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, max, identity

I have a table `CMT_M_DISPOSITION (DispositionKey, DispositionValue)`. PK is on `DispositionKey`. I wish to insert a new record by using `MAX(DispositionKey) + 1` for the  first column.

I get an error

> Invalid column DispositionKey

when I run the below code.

Can anybody explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT EY_CMT_TestV2..CMT_M_DISPOSITION ON

Insert into CMT_M_DISPOSITION (DispositionKey, DispositionValue) 
values (MAX(DispositionKey) + 1, 'Newest')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT EY_CMT_TestV2..CMT_M_DISPOSITION OFF
```

Comment: You're trying to select the MAX(DispositionKey) from the table in an `INSERT`, which is why it's throwing the error.  Though, I'm curious, why not just let the ID Auto Increment?

Comment: `Insert into CMT_M_DISPOSITION(DispositionKey,DispositionValue) select (MAX(DispositionKey) + 1, 'Newest') from CMT_M_DISPOSITION` ????

Comment: The comment by @BhupeshC (INSERT INTO.. SELECT) does the insert successfully then why my insert statement is failing?

Comment: Uhhhhh... why don't you just let the identity column do its thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT EY_CMT_TestV2..CMT_M_DISPOSITION ON

  Insert into CMT_M_DISPOSITION(DispositionKey,DispositionValue) select MAX(DispositionKey) + 1, 'Newest' from CMT_M_DISPOSITION 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT EY_CMT_TestV2..CMT_M_DISPOSITION OFF
```

The identity insert allows you to insert explicit values (in this case, the explicit value defined in INSERT INTO ... SELECT) and hence needs to be turned ON before the insert.

Comment: well the basic is, if you need to insert column data you use `insert select` statement